# Google Apps script: make the radio field required

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

It may be a simple one for the expert. But I'm not able to figure it out.

I have a google apps script that shows two radio buttons.

```
var txtGender = app.createTextBox().setName('txtGender').setVisible(false);
var hdlMale = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtGender).setText('Male');
var rdMale = app.createRadioButton('gender','Male').addValueChangeHandler(hdlMale);
var hdlFemale = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtGender).setText('Female');
var rdFemale = app.createRadioButton('gender','Female').addValueChangeHandler(hdlFemale);
var pos = 0; 
regGrid.setWidget(pos, 1, rdMale).setWidget(pos,2,rdFemale).setWidget(pos,3,txtGender);
pos++;
```

The above script shows two radio buttons - Male, Female.

How do I make this group a required field?

Also if 'Male' option is selected I want to display a text message below these radio buttons how do I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's a google form or an UiApp right?

You'll have to move to HTMLService, you can start in [Formfuse](http://formfuse.io/) to transform your Google Form to a HTML, then read about serving HTML pages trough google apps in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

That's the only way I know.